# How to call the XPath position() function in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Here is my XML code:

**test.xml**

```
<l>
    <i>
        <a>AAA</a>
        <b>BBB</b>
        <c>CCC</c>
    </i>
    <i>
        <a>AAA2</a>
        <b>BBB2</b>
        <c>CCC2</c>
    </i>
    <i>
        ...
    </i>
</l>
```

I want to extract the 2nd `c` node with Java. I tried the code below:

**test.java**

```
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document d = docBuilder.parse("file:///C:/path/to/my/test.xml");

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//c[position()=2]");

// The following line raises a NPE
System.out.println("> " + ((Node) expr.evaluate(d, XPathConstants.NODE)).getTextContent());
```

However the `evaluate` method returns null value thus a NullPointerException (NPE) is raised.

What am I missing?

**Java 6**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[]` operator has higher precedence than `//` which is causing the problem. Using

```
(//c)[position()=2]
```

instead, solved the problem, when I tried.

Comment: Where does this "higher precedence" come from?

Comment: This links lists all the operators in XPath 1, along with the precedence https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/xslt-2nd-edition/9780596527211/apbs08.html

Comment: If I run `//i[position()=2]`, I get the second `i` only.

Comment: @Stephan Yes, but the reason is not what you had in mind. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

What happens is this: Positional predicates in XPath usually apply to the nodes of the input tree, not to an intermediate result sequence. An XPath expression like

```
//c[position() = 2]       |   or //c[2]
```

means:

> Select all element nodes `c` anywhere in the input document, if they are the **second `c` child of their parent element**.

Now let's have a look at your input document:

```
<l>
    <i>
        <a>AAA</a>
        <b>BBB</b>
        <c>CCC</c>
    </i>
    <i>
        <a>AAA2</a>
        <b>BBB2</b>
        <c>CCC2</c>
    </i>
    <i>
        ...
    </i>
</l>
```

Both `c` elements in it are the *first* `c` child of their parent, that's why the result set is empty.

What you *intended* to do is

- in a first step find all `c` elements present in the input document
- only take the *second* of those nodes in something like an intermediate result sequence

and that's exactly what parentheses around `//c` does:

```
(//c)[2]
```

---

> If I run //i[position()=2], I get the second i only.

There actually *is* an `i` element in the input which is the second `i` child of its parent element. But still, this expression does not always return a single item. If the structure of your input document were like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <l>
        <i>
            <a>AAA</a>
            <b>BBB</b>
            <c>CCC</c>
        </i>
        <i>
            <a>AAA2</a>
            <b>BBB2</b>
            <c>CCC2</c>
        </i>
        <i>
            ...
        </i>
    </l>
    <l>
        <i>
            <a>AAA</a>
            <b>BBB</b>
            <c>CCC</c>
        </i>
        <i>
            <a>AAA2</a>
            <b>BBB2</b>
            <c>CCC2</c>
        </i>
        <i>
            ...
        </i>
    </l>
</root>
```

then `//i[2]` would return *two* `i` elements.

Comment: `//c[2]` returns all the `c` elements in the document that are the _second c_ in their respective parents, not the _second child_.  All the `c` elements in the example input are the _first c_ in their parents, which is why `//c[2]` returns nothing - there are no "second c" elements in the document.

Comment: @IanRoberts That's what I meant - but it should be more clear, I agree. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @IanRoberts Thanks for your comment, that part was actually downright wrong - I've corrected it now.